# Problema con envio de formulario usando php y js

Tags: php, javascript, mvc, formularios

Buen día, además de tener un problema, lo que creo tener es una duda teórica: Vengo haciendo un sistema con varios **CRUDs** aplicando el modelo **MVC**. En todos mis **CRUDs** sigo los mismos pasos: **archivo.php** que hace la llamada al **controlador.php** justo antes del cierre de la etiqueta `form`, el **controlador.php** procesa y verifica los datos, los envía al **modelo.php** y este hace lo suyo comunicándose con la DB.

Lo que me pasa en el ultimo **CRUD** es que, el botón `submit` de este formulario, ademas de enviarlo, tiene un par de acciones `onClick` en un **archivo.js**.

Menciono esto de las acciones `JS` porque es el único botón `submit` de todos mis formularios que tiene este tipo de comportamientos, y el **CRUD** no funciona (específicamente la Creación de elementos)

Sospecho fuertemente que tiene algo que ver el hecho que el botón ejecute acciones en `JS`, pero no estoy seguro y por ahí le estoy errando en algo. Agradecería que me pudieran ayudar.

A continuación coloco mis códigos:

**crear-menu.php**

```
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="botonGuardar">Guardar Menú</button>
  </div>
</form>
<?php
  $crearMenu = new ControladorViandas();
  $crearMenu -> ctrCrearVianda();
?>
```

**EDIT 1**:Ya probé colocar este código `php` tanto dentro como fuera de las etiquetas `form`, con idéntico resultado en ambos intentos.

**menu.js** con esta acción, recojo datos del formulario y los guardo como un `string` en el `val` de un elemento de mi `html`, para recogerla luego con las variables `$_POST[]`. No se si es buena idea.

```
$(".botonGuardar").click(function() {

// Creo el objeto JSON 

listaIngredientes = [];

$(".listaIngredientes").each(function() {
    var ingrediente = $(this).children(".col-6").children().children(".nuevoNombreIngrediente").val();
    var cantidad = $(this).children(".col-2").children(".nuevaCantidadIngrediente").val();
    var precio = $(this).children(".ingresoPrecio").children().children(".precioIngrediente").val();
    var unidad = $(this).children(".div-unidad").children(".unidad-de-medida").val()


    listaIngredientes.push({
        "ingrediente": ingrediente,
        "cantidad": cantidad,
        "unidad": unidad,
        "precio": precio
    })
})



$("#ingredientesFinal").val(JSON.stringify(listaIngredientes));


});
```

**controlador.php** Como pueden observar, hay unos mensajes `js` de consola en el **codigo php**. Cuando entro a **crear-menu.php** la consola arroja de una "no hay variable post nuevo menu", pero cuando envío el formulario no arroja ninguna de las dos consolas. Es como que nunca vuelve a ejecutar el método para crear un nuevo menú/vianda

```
 static public function ctrCrearVianda(){

    if(isset($_POST["nuevoMenu"])){
        echo '<script>console.log("hay variable post nuevo menu")</script>';

        if(  preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜ ]+$/', $_POST["nuevoMenu"])) {
            $tabla = "viandas";

            $datos = array(
            "nombre" => $_POST["nuevoMenu"],
            "id_cliente" => $_POST["seleccionarCliente"],
            "productos" => $_POST["ingredientesFinal"],
            "costo" => $_POST["nuevoPrecioMenu"],
            "dmc" => $_POST["nuevoDmc"]
            );

           $respuesta = ModeloViandas::mdlCrearVianda($tabla,$datos);

           if($respuesta == "ok"){

            // El menu se creó correctamente

            echo '<script>
            swal.fire({
                type: "success",
                title: "El menu ha sido creado correctamente",
                showConfirmButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                closeOnConfirm: false

            }).then(function(result){
                if(result.value){
                    var url = window.location
                    var parts = url.toString().split("/");
                    var lastSegment = parts.pop() || parts.pop();
                    window.location = lastSegment;

                }   

            });
            </script>';
        } 
        }else{
            //EL NOMBRE DE MENU NO PUEDE LLEVAR CARACTERES ESPECIALES
        }
    }else{
        echo '<script>console.log("no hay variable post nuevo menu")</script>';
    }


}
```

**modelo.php** Por ultimo dejo el modelo, aunque es en vano porque estoy casi seguro que este esta bien, y ademas el error que devuelve el sistema hace que directamente ni se interactue con este archivo.

```
 /*============================================
CARGAR VIANDA
============================================*/

static public function mdlCrearVianda($tabla, $datos){


    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(nombre, id_cliente, productos, costo, dmc) VALUES ( :nombre, :id_cliente, :productos, :costo, :dmc)");   

    $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id_cliente", $datos["id_cliente"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":productos", $datos["productos"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":costo", $datos["costo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":dmc", $datos["dmc"], PDO::PARAM_STR);


    if($stmt->execute()){

        return "ok";

    }else{
        return "error";
    }

    $stmt -> close();

    $stmt = null;



}
```

Comment: Estaba pensando que si mi problema es como lo estoy pensando, que hay algún inconveniente por el llamado a ``JS`` y en simultaneo a ``PHP``, tal vez pueda hacer la conexión con el controlador directamente desde mi ``js`` usando ``Ajax``. No se que les parece?

Comment: No he probado tu código. Pero, al leerlo me parece que el método click que asocias al botón **sólo crea el objeto JSON** pero en ninguna parte se hace algo con el. **No se ve que sea enviado** pues button no tiene declarado el atributo *action* y no hay orden de hacer post.

Comment: El js funciona y hace lo que debe, que es, al notar el click en el botón con la clase botonGuardar, recoge datos de los campos, los carga en un array, pasa todo el array a String y lo coloca en el value de un input. Mi problema está en realidad con la llamada al controlador, desde el archivo crear-menú.php

Comment: esta linea ``$("#ingredientesFinal").val(JSON.stringify(listaIngredientes));
`` es la que devuelve el string al valor de un elemento html, que yo luego voy a querer enviar como variable post. El tema es que el ``luego`` es relativo porq es el mismo boton que hace las dos acciones, por lo que se dispararian en simultaneo. Cuando llegue a mi casa voy a probar hacer todo mediante ajax y comento como me fue.

Comment: Espera. Si usas unBind() antes de ligar el click y luego en el método usado para preparar la data, al terminar, ejecutas submit()  se resuelve.

Comment: Fui a buscar la documentacion y aparentemente ese metodo quedo obsoleto, ahora es off(), de todas maneras no entiendo bien lo que planteas. Si no te molesta intentar una respuesta te agradeceria, yo voy a pelear con mi cerebro tratando de leer ingles a ver si puedo aplicar ese metodo que me decis. Gracias

Comment: por lo que entiendo lo que vos decis es como "pausar" el evento ``js`` que crea el elemento, ejecutar el ``php`` y luego retomar el ``js``? La idea seria al reves, que primero se ejecute el ``js``, ya que ``php`` requiere el dato devuelto por este. Lo googlee, pero aparentemente no se hace ni es recomendado, retrasar un script php, por lo que lei

Comment: Acabo de publicar una respuesta que posiblemente sea castigada por los ortodoxos, que a mi me suele funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes colocar un event.prevenDefault() y ahí agregar la datas que deseas agregar y luego hacer el submit...

```
$('#tuboton')click(function(e) {
   e.preventDeafault();
   //introducir el código aquí ejecutas acciones para asignar la data 
   $('#form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola @Mani voy a intentar una respuesta poco ortodoxa pero que yo suelo usar cuando necesito ciertos comportamientos previos al envio de los formularios:

Al enlazar (ligar **bind()**) el comportamiento deseado para el evento **click**, se lo está adicionando a su comportamiento normal, de modo que ambos comportamientos van a dispararse. Para evitar que el comportamiento por defecto sea lanzado primero, o que ambos se ejecuten sin saber a ciencia cierta cual va primero se debe empezar por desvincular el comportamiento por defecto (en este caso disparar el submit del formulario) así:

```
<script lang="javascript">

$('.botonGuardar').unbind('click'); // desactiva el comportamiento por defecto
$('.botonGuardar').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  // tu código pasando la información
  // ...
  // Y ahora disparas controlado el submit del formulario:
$('#selector_de_form').submit();
}); // Fin del método
</script>
```

De esta forma tienes una solución sencilla que asegura que el envio del formulario se haga con la data preparada debidamente.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funcionó a la perfección.

Comment: En ese caso es cuestión de cortesía marcarla como correcta. Me alegra que te haya servido. :-_^:

Comment: Lo hice en el momento de comentar, tal vez el sistema se toma un tiempo. Ahora me estoy yendo al trabajo, pero tengo la sospecha que tu solucion, al retrasar la carga del array, hara que el mismo viaje vacio al php. Lo corroborare luego, pero vi que tu solucion hizo que el metodo avance y me tire la Sweet Alert. Mas tarde comento como fue.